# Host header for Ionic proxy config

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, proxy, ionic3

How can I add Host header to Ionic proxy config ?
I need to define the Host header to access Kong API gateway.

Here is my ionic.config.json file

```
 {
"name": "test_name",
"app_id": "test_id",
"type": "ionic-angular",
"integrations": {
    "cordova": {}
  },
"proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/api/test",
      "proxyUrl": "http://docker-test:6200/test"
    }
  ]
}
```